# I have a sentence whose words consist of individual text views, how to calculate the right distance between the TextViews?

Tags: android, android-layout

For some reason, sentences in my app consist of individual TextViews, one for each word. Of course, the sentence created in this way should look as if it were a single string in a TextView. For this I have to add every Text View a certain value for the attribute "padding right". In the final version, this distance should be exactly the same as if it were a string in a TextView. I do not want to estimate the value for this distance, is there a formula that leads to the right result?

The TextViews are just grouped in a LinearLayout of horizontal orientation

```
 <LinearLayout
        style="@style/phraseCardViewSubContainer">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word1G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word2G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word3G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word4G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word5G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word6G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word7G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word8G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word9G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word10G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word11G"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word12G"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you provide us some code of where you see the multiple TextViews?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a textView with your typeface features, set its text to a space (or whatever gap-size you want) and measure its width like:

```
textView.setText(" ");
textView.measure(0, 0);       //must call measure!
yourInt = textView.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Then use that value to create the gaps in between your other textViews.

I'm not sure how `dp` influences this.. another way would be to just put that textview inbetween each of your word-textviews and make the text non-selectable.